# Tackling variational problem with constraints

Tags: symbolic, inequalities, constraint, variational-calculus

I need to minimize (preferably symbolically) functional with constraints:

$$
F = \int_{0}^{\pi/2} f(x)cos{x}dx\,\\
1.1 \geq f(x) \geq 0\\
2.\int_{0}^{\pi/2} f(x)dx=Const\\
3. f(0) =1\\
4.f(\pi/2) = 0\\
$$

Is there any way to solve problem like this? Could this problem be solved in principle?

Thanks in advance